# Redirect webpage to link in Iframe

Tags: iframe, html

Currently, I am creating a webpage which use search tool of Google.com. 
- I made a form on the page which will sent query form to Google.com.
- For the search result, I used I an iframe to display those content.

But the problem is: when the iframe displays search result links, If user click on those link, only the content in the iframe got redirect to the result webpage, while I want the link to redirect the main page itself.

Is there a solution for this ?

The code for my main page
- The searchFrame is where the form is
- The contentFrame is just an empty page.

'

```
    <div id="sidecontainer">
<iframe id="SFrame" name="SearchFrame" frameborder ="0" width="500" height="100" scrolling="no" src="SearchBox.html"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="content">
<iframe id="CFrame" name="ContentFrame" frameborder="0" width="80%" height="900px" scrolling="no" OnLoad="window.scroll(0, 0);" src="ContentFrame.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

'

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use base tag. Add this to the head of the iframe. This will open all the links in the parent page itself

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

This is supported in all browsers too.

Comment: Thanks, but that work for static webpage, but my iframe will be changed completely as it presented the result page of google.com. Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: if this in the head tag on clicking on the link it will be opened in the parent page